# Is there other way to write this if code?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I Have just started to learn c#. I am most comfortable with if and if else. Right now I am working on a program where it writes an IP address and I need to type the correct subnet, and all that. It takes too long time to make the code with if and else if, so I was wondering if there is a faster way to do it.

```
Random r = new Random();
            int randomip = r.Next(256);
            int secondip = r.Next(256);
            int subnetip = r.Next(24, 31);
            int numbers = subnetip;

Console.WriteLine("192.168." + randomip + "." + secondip + "/" + subnetip);

            Console.Write("Type the correct netID: ");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Type the correct subnet: ");
            Console.ReadLine();


            if (numbers == 24)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("correct netID is: 192.168." + randomip + 
                "." + secondip / 256);
                Console.WriteLine("correct subnet is: 255.255.255.0");
            } else if (numbers == 25)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("correct netID is: 192.168." + randomip + 
                "." + secondip / 128);
                Console.WriteLine("correct subnet is: 255.255.255.128");
            } else if (numbers == 26)
```

and so on… with other numbers. Isn’t there a faster and easier way to make it work? It works but if I want to add more numbers there would be a problem

Comment: what is the pattern here that makes you devide `secondip` once by 256, once by 128, ...?

Comment: U could use a [Switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch)...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you think backwards, these are your divisors based on the value of `numbers`

```
31 => 2
30 => 4
29 => 8
28 => 16
27 => 32
26 => 64
25 => 128
24 => 256
```

In other words, they're two to the power of an incrementing number.

```
31 => 2^1
30 => 2^2
29 => 2^3
28 => 2^4
27 => 2^5
26 => 2^6
25 => 2^7
24 => 2^8
```

In other words, two to the power of 32 minus `numbers`

```
31 => 2^(32-31)
30 => 2^(32-30)
29 => 2^(32-29)
28 => 2^(32-28)
27 => 2^(32-27)
26 => 2^(32-26)
25 => 2^(32-25)
24 => 2^(32-24)
```

In other words,

```
var divisor = Math.Pow(2, 32-numbers);
var subnet = 256 - divisor;
```

Down to 4 lines with no `switch` or `if`. Yay!

```
Console.WriteLine("correct netID is: 192.168." + randomip + "." + secondip / divisor);
Console.WriteLine("correct subnet is: 255.255.255." + subnet);
```